# Wrapping JSTree in an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I have two fiddles that have the same jstree loading in. One is wrapped in an angular directive, the other is not. I am new to angular. I am not seeing any of the images in the angular version. Also the animations do not work. Am I missing a jstree plugin, or do I need to add a bind function that will add in this functionality?

Here is the fiddle: (not in angular js)

Here is the simple js tree code :

```
   $('#tree').jstree({
'plugins' : ['themes', 'json_data', 'checkbox', 'types'],
  'icon':false,
'checkbox' : {
  'two_state' : true // Nessesary to disable default checking childrens
},
 "json_data" : {
                        "data" : [
    {
        "data" : "Basics",
        "state" : "open",
        "children" : [{
            "data" : "login",
            "state" : "closed",
            "children" : [ "login", {"data" : "results", "state" : "open"} ]
        },


            {
                "data" : "Basics",
                "state" : "closed",
                "children" : [ "login", "something",{"data" : "results", "state" : "closed"} ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data" : "All",
        "state" : "closed",
        "children" : [ {
            "data" : "AddCustomer",
            "state" : "closed",
            "children" : [ "login","Add", {"data" : "results", "state" : "closed"} ]
        }    ]
    }
]
                    },
"types" : {
  "types": {
    "disabled" : { // Defining new type 'disabled'
      "check_node" : false, 
      "uncheck_node" : false 
    }, 
    "default" : { // Override default functionality
      "check_node" : function (node) {
        $(node).children('ul').children('li').children('a').children('.jstree-checkbox').click();
        return true;
      },
      "uncheck_node" : function (node) {
        $(node).children('ul').children('li').children('a').children('.jstree-checkbox').click();
        return true;
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/R3vZv/

Here is a plunker with the angular directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xHIc4J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well on your plunker, you are getting a 404 on the jstree style sheet, put this HTML in your plunker and viola! I am referencing the CSS from the authors web site. I suggest you pull it down and put the right CSS path in there

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>jsTreeAngular</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hqnetworks.pl/strassmayr_zpf/web/js/themes/default/style.css" />
       <script  type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js" ></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-app="jsTreeApp">
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            <jstree data="5"></jstree>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How dare you blame Angular! Kidding :)

Comment: Yup, I just realized this after creating the examples. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

On my current AngularJS project, we are integrating jsTree in a directive. It started pretty well, but very fast it became a nightmare. I can't recall half the problems we encountered, but we painfully ended up with a bunch of buggy, convoluted code. It would have been a better idea to just write our tree directive from scratch.

However, I just ran into a project I wish I had know about before :

https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat

It's exactly what we needed, it's pure AngularJS (which is a HUGE benefit, no more jQuery events to register to), and the creator is a well known and respected individual in the AngularJS community (the way I structure my apps owes him and his blog a lot).

In general it's not a good idea to wrap an existing jQuery-based library with an Angular directive, and it's especially true in this particular case. Save yourself the pain and go pure Angular.